# How to register mediator's IPipelineBehavior with Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, mediator, mediatr

I'm trying to understand how to set up pipeline behaviours with mediator.

My command:

```
public class MyUpdateCommand : IRequest<CommandResult>
{
   // fields       
}
```

My handler:

```
public class MyUpdateCommandHandler : RequestHandler<MyUpdateCommand, CommandResult>
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _repository;

    public GasDetailsUpdateCommandHandler(IMyRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    protected override CommandResult HandleCore(MyUpdateCommand command)
    {  
        {
            _repository.Update(command);
            return CommandResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's say I want to handle all exceptions raised in RequestHandlers that return a `CommandResult` by logging them and returning the message in my `CommandResult` object. I've created this class:

```
public class ExceptionLoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> 
   : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> where TResponse : CommandResult
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public ExceptionLoggingBehavior(ILog logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, 
       CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        try
        {
            return await next();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex.Message);
            return (TResponse) CommandResult.Fail(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to put into my inversion of control container (AutoFac)?